# Keep old data if file input is empty ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm updating my product (in code it is "urun") details on database. When file input is empty GorselURL column gets blank. It is okay if I add an image again on edit, but when I do that it uploads same image. How can I keep old data if file input is empty?

My controller edit action (UrunDuzenle):

```
    //POST
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UrunDuzenle([FromForm] Urunler obj)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (obj.Gorsel != null)
            {
                string folder = "images/products/";
                folder += Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + obj.Gorsel.FileName;
                obj.GorselURL = folder;
                string serverFolder = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, folder);
                await obj.Gorsel.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(serverFolder, FileMode.Create));
            }
            _db.tblUrunler.Add(obj);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["success"] = "Ürün ekleme başarılı";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(obj);
    }
```

`obj.Gorsel` line returns null.

My Urunler model:

```
public class Urunler
{
    [Key]
    public int UrunID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string UrunAdi { get; set; }
    public string UrunAciklamasi { get; set; }
    public int UrunKategorisi { get; set; }
    public int UrunFiyati { get; set; }
    public int StokDurumu { get; set; }
    public int RenkSecenekleri { get; set; }
    public int BoyutSecenekleri { get; set; }
    public int Indirim { get; set; }
    public int TedarikciID { get; set; }
    public int GelisFiyati { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile Gorsel { get; set; }
    public string GorselURL { get; set; }
}
```

And Form in my view:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="UrunDuzenle">
    <input asp-for="UrunID" hidden />
    <div class="border p-3 mt-4">
        <div class="row pb-2">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Ürün Düzenle</h2>
            <hr />
        </div>
        @*<div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>*@
        <div class="row g-2" id="urunEklemeFormu">
            // Other inputs here

               // File input
                <div class="mb-3 form-floating col-md">
                    <label asp-for="GorselURL" class="control-label"></label>
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input asp-for="Gorsel" class="custom-file-input form-control" type="file" id="formFile">
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="formFile">Dosya seç</label>
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Gorsel" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3 form-floating col-md">
                    <img src="~/@Model.GorselURL" class="adminUrunGorseli" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px">Kaydet</button>
        <a asp-controller="urun" asp-action="index" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width:150px">
            Geri Dön
        </a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: "obj.Gorsel line returns null."  Which line upload Gorsel in your view ode?

Comment: @QingGuo great! Thanks LOL! changed `asp-for` value to `Gorsel`. That worked.

Comment: "Keep old data if file input is empty" Do you mean <input type="hidden" asp-for="xx"/>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks to @QingGuo hidden input is my solution.

My original code was deleting file name from table field. So I added a hidden input for `GorselURL` and gave a default value from Model/Database.

```
// File input div
<div class="mb-3 form-floating col-md">
                        <label asp-for="Gorsel" class="control-label"></label>
                        <div class="custom-file">
                            <label class="custom-file-label" for="formFile">Dosya seç</label>
                            <input asp-for="Gorsel" class="custom-file-input form-control" type="file" id="formFile">
                            <input asp-for="GorselURL" type="hidden" value="@Model.GorselURL"/>
                        </div>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Gorsel" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
//.
```